Cheap and easy way to make halogen bulb last longer
I have a dozen security guards that use 12v 100 watt halogen spotlights connected to 12 V batteries to do patrols on the ocean. Let acid batteries had all kinds of problems and I switch to lithium. However, the increased voltage is pulling more current through the lightbulb than it can handle and they are burning out really quick. At 12 V the lightbulb pulls exactly the hundred watts is rated for.  with lithium operating voltage around 14.4 V. It's up to around 130 W so they're burning out. What's the easiest way to limit current? I'm not too concerned about efficiency, but I am a little bit concerned about heat as the battery and anything electric needs to be inside a fibreglass box we've made. To keep it waterproof. I have ordered some 20 amp bucks converters off eBay, but they'll take a month to get here, I can't go through that many bulbs until then, and I suspect they will burn up quickly or get reverse polarity killed or wet or something will happen for sure to them. it just feels too complicated for a task which has no room for complication.  I have access to all the dead appliances and electrical gear. You can imagine so harvesting components is definitely possible, any suggestions?

We don't know the system (bulb type, battery type and configuration, how much space you have, what additional circuitry is in there, etc) so we can't give very useful recommendations but they will likely be: change your battery chemistry, change your bulb, or wait for the buck converters to arrive. There's unfortunately not a lot you can do to McGuyver away 30W. What do you mean by "no room for complication"?

14.4 V is solid for 4S. You could go LiFePO (I'd expect ~12.5 V - you do measure at the lamp, not at the battery, don't you), but: why stick with incandescent lamps?

i like to use series diode(s) to subtract voltage without much regard to load, 0.3v on a Schottky, 0.6v on a rectifier diode. BTW, measure your new battery when it's under load (in use), it should be more like 13.5v than 14.4v.

Anything really simple will dissipate a lot of heat (about 30W), and, of course, waste almost 1/4 of the energy. Maybe you could arrange some kind of resistor that snakes outside the box and cools itself in the water or in air.
For example, some steel wire inside a tube.  Galvanized 19 gauge steel wire (about 1mm diameter or 9.78mm^2 cross-section area) at Home Depot is cheap $9 CAD for 165'. Probably something similar is available in your area.
If you want to drop 14.4 -12V = 2.4V at 8.3A you'd need about 0.29Ω, which, if the Internet is to be believed, would take around 1m of wire. Stainless steel would probably be better.
About a couple metres of 9.5mm wide x 0.6mm thick stainless steel strapping from the scrap bin would be about right too, and would cool itself more easily.
You can test the resistance with a multimeter. If you don't have anything that will measure 290mΩ accurately, just adjust the length until the right voltage appears across the lamp.

That is the perfect answer, I have a ton of stainless steel wire around and a multimeter with that resolution. Perfect thank you.

@SVSavannah to measure 290mΩ accurately you need a multimeter with a resistance range below 1000 mΩ using the Kelvin four-terminal sensing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing

If these are standard PAR 46 (5.75") spotlights like they use on police cars they are available in LED. These are rated at 30 W, 50,000 hours vs. 100 W, 100 hours for the equivalent halogens ones.
I’m not sure if the higher voltage of the lithium batteries will be a problem. In a vehicle you can get up to 14.5 V with the engine running so it should be okay but even if you need to add some resistance to drop it a volt it would only dissipate around 3 W so it’s not as bad as with the halogens.
They are quite a bit more expensive, probably 4 to 5 times as much, but at a few hours a night use you'd probably go through half a dozen halogens a year whereas the LED will last many years, so it pays off over time.

I am not sure if you can manage with slightly less light output. But if that's a viable option, you can try this:
Currently, you have 100 W lights rated for 12 V. This means the bulb resistance is around 1.44 ohms.
If you connect two such bulbs in series, and power them up using a battery, you will get effectively 72 W.
This will give a lower light output but certainly will stop the failures you see. Try it out if it is feasible at your end.

bulb resistance is around 1.44 ohms at 12 V. While you don't spell out whether to expect 72 W for each of two series connected incandescent bulbs or for the two combined, it hardly matters because light temperature as well as efficiency will be down the drain - at 7.2 V (see question), worse still at 6 V. And the resistance will be much lower. (And how did you arrive at 72 W?)
